# Are Activities essentially files/pages for an app?

Tags: android

Should I look at it that way when determining if I should create an activity?

Comment: No.  An Activity is the object that manages the current view on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question many Android devs have asked and debated on and the point of view has evolved over the years but you'll still get subjective responses depending on who you ask.  Activities *may* have started out that way - as a way to encapsulate a specific page that forms part of a bigger task - and thus their model as stack.

The more 'modern' point of view and this is the opinionated view of Google Android devs, is to think of a single (or more) Activity as a hook to system events and as a container  for a set of Fragments that implement the actual pages.  This sort of reminds me of how single page web applications are built.  You can learn more about it here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles

If you're looking for an initial point of view, that's a good place to start and you can evolve your own point of view from there.

I tend to have a middle ground.  I tend to group my app into functional pieces (e.g. setup wizard, user management, home page etc.) and each will typically have an Activity which hosts more than one or more fragments that represent the pages

Comment: I would say an Activity is a workflow.  It may map to a page, it may map to several pages (via fragments or other methods), it may map to many pages (for example, an activity to display an abstract data type).

Answer (score 0):

A book to an app (or any program) comparison is too narrow. It's better to compare an app to an iceberg.

**The tip** (visible part) of the iceberg are the activities, simply put, the things the eye could see.

**The bottom part** (the part that is in the water) of the iceberg are underlying codes, background threads (processes e.g. threads, services...), simply put, the things users don't know about.

Answer (score -1):

Sure! No obligation to have Activity in your application since you can have an application with only a service. ...and no need to get into AIDL unless you want to.

The problem is, how to make the application run. When you create an application with an Activity, you add an Intent filter, in the manifest, that makes the activity startable from the Launcher. If there's no activity, you'll have to find another way to start it.

It is easy to do, though. Just fire an intent from one of your other programs, like this:

```
startService(new Intent("my.service.intent"));
```

... where the service is registered your manifest, like this:

```
    <service android:name=".SomeService" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="my.service.intent"/>
      </intent-filter>
```

Of course `startService` and `broadcastIntent` are a bit clunky if you really need a complex API between applications and your service. If you need something richer, you will want to look into AIDL and a Bound Service.

Comment: I think this is rather a more advanced answer for the question. Though, it will help him out to understand services if he ever encounters services.